# Help with jQuery grabbing json data

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am having some trouble here, my json data is outputting as follows:

```
{"date":[{"day_w":"Tuesday","day_n":"28","month":"Dec"}],"subscriptions":[{"subscribe":"example1"},{"subscribe":"example2"},{"subscribe":"example3"}]}
```

I am using the jQuery code:

```
$.getJSON("example.php",function(data){

$.each(data.subscriptions, function(i, item) {
    var subscribeData = "<li>"+ item.subscribe +"</li>";
    $('#list').append(subscribeData);
});
```

but I am having an issue grabbing the date array. I don't want to have to use .each because there is only one array holding the date. Does this make sense? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Are you going to use the date value within the `$.each()` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is `date` an array at all? Why not just have the object in there directly?

```
{"date":{"day_w":"Tuesday","day_n":"28","month":"Dec"},"subscriptions":[...
```

If that's not an option, you can just access `date[0]`:

```
doSomethingWith(data.date[0].day_w);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write `data.date[0]` to get the first object in the array.

Comment: its returning [object Object]

Comment: That's because it is an object.  You probably want one of the object's properties.

Answer (score 1):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/bAtEW/